# Integer linear programming (ILP) formulation of connectivity of induced subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, integer-programming

Can anyone assist me to find out what should be the ILP formulation of a case when I try to label vertices by say $0$, $1$ and $2$ and want the subgraph of graph $(V,E)$ made by same vertex set but edge set being those which have at least one end point as $1$ or $2$, to be connected. I don't need objective functions, just want to know how to show this as a constraint.

Comment: Your title says induced subgraph, but your description says the same vertex set. Are vertices with label 0 and no neighbors with label 1 or 2 supposed to be included?

Comment: @RobPratt No, those vertices need not be included. But based on some other constraints I am getting all the vertices. So, to simplify I have told that people need not worry about reduced vertices and vertex set remains same.

Comment: I had asked a similar question about two years ago: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282302/lp-constraints-for-connected-subgraphs-of-fixed-size

Comment: you can find an answer also here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/282317/31310

Answer (score 1):

[*Imposing contiguity constraints in political districting models*](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2020/01/7582.pdf), by Hamidreza Validi, Austin Buchanan, and Eugene Lykhovyd, is a very recent paper (January 27, 2020) that provides a good survey of integer linear programming models for connectivity in the context of political districting.

Answer (score 0):

[A NEW MIXED INTEGER LINEAR PROGRAMMING FORMULATION FOR THE MAXIMUM DEGREE BOUNDED CONNECTED SUBGRAPH PROBLEM](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/119/publn119p99-108.pdf)

This paper helped me understand a lot on connectivity of subgraphs. A must look for those seeking an answer.

Comment: The paper seems to suggest that, for large enough instances, a polynomial formulation yields faster solve times than an exponential formulation. This is not necessarily true if the exponential constraints are generated dynamically only when they are violated. As a famous example, consider the Miller-Tucker-Zemlin and Dantzig-Fulkerson-Johnson formulations for the traveling salesman problem.